# Github pushed changes not visible on my react app

Tags: reactjs, windows, github, visual-studio-code, repository

My problem is that whenever I commit/push a new change to my github repository, the code changes but the app remains the same.

Any ideas what can I improve?

I did this:

- GITHUB: create new repository
- VS-CONSOLE: `npx create-react-app .`
- VS-CONSOLE: `npm start`
- VS-CONSOLE: `ctrl+c`
- VS-CONSOLE: `npm i gh-pages`
- package.json:
  above scripts `"homepage": "https://account-name.github.io/respository-name"`,
  in scripts: `"deploy": "gh-pages -d build"`
- VS-CONSOLE: `git init`, `git add .` , `git commit -m 'initial'`,

  git remote add
  origin https://account-name.github.io/respository-name

  git push
  -u origin master
- GITHUB: refresh page
- VS-CONSOLE: `npm run build`
- VS-CONSOLE: `npm run deploy`
- GITHUB: refresh page

Comment: Where/when do you build the app, and how are you deploying/hosting it?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my post to reach a better understanding. I'm building the app in VS Code and I'm deploying it in VS console with the comands above.

Comment: That looks like it should be working. Do you have a link to the github repo we could have a look at?

Comment: Have you checked the gh-pages branch contains the correct build files? Also have you set up github to use that branch for deployment? And what do you do to the code that you would expect something to change, are you deploying every time?

Comment: Link to my repo: https://github.com/Danielioanitescu92/covid

Even if I'm changing a little bit of css styling in VS Code i.e., I save the css file, I commit, I push to Github.
Than I go to my github repo, I refresh and I can see those changes. But nothing changes on my app.

I only deployed the app first time I pushed it to github. Should I run 'npm run deploy' every time I commit/push a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that your deploy scripts are set up, just pushing to master isn't sufficient. Yes you need to run deploy every time you want the app to update.

This is so that you can push as many commits as you want whilst working on your code, as a work-in-progress, then when you are ready to update your app, you need to run the `deploy` script, which will build the app and put it on the `gh-pages` branch so that it is picked up by github pages and put on the web.

Committing is like saving and backing up your work, deploying is like handing it in.

Comment: Yes, this is it. This is what I was missing. 'npm run deploy' everytime after commit. Thanks, Luke! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries!
Just remember, it doesn't have to be after commit, you can deploy any time. 

Commit = save+backup source code, deploy = put on the website

Comment: I totally get it now. Thanks again, mate! I'll keep that in mind.